# Can WSO2 use two identity providers acting as one?

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I have an instance of WSO2 using CAS and SAML. They are both working and pull from the same identity source, Active Directory. I have multiple service providers, some use CAS and some use SAML. There is one thing stopping this from being a true SSO system. CAS and SAML don't work together.

If someone logs in with CAS, they have access to all CAS service providers (until timeout anyway). If they log in to a SAML service provider, they have access to all SAML service providers (< timeout). They do not have access to the other identity providers. If you log in with CAS, you have to log in again with a SAML identity provider, and the reverse.

Is there a way to log in with one and be authorized for both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me echo your question again, just to verify whether I got it correctly.

You have WSO2 Identity server instance. There are multiple service providers(for your applications) configured. Part of them use SAML to authenticate. Rest use CAS.

If above is correct, true SSO should already be supported in WSO2 Identity Server. They had the feature lacking for SLO though, but I believe latest versions do have it.

What is the version you are using?

Comment: Yes, that's about it. There are other service providers using identity providers other than CAS and SAML, but they are not mine.

It's Version 5.3.0

Comment: I'm not sure about 5.3 though. You can try their slack channel and provide this with the IS version. https://wso2.com/community/slack/

Comment: It just started working, some time over the Thanksgiving break. Maybe my occasional "What is the point of SSO, if it doesn't act like SSO?" finally got through to someone. Now if can get someone to change a certain setting I don't have access to, but that I have given them the instructions to change. 

Thanks